# How to edit GeoTIFF file downloaded from NASA worldview?

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, editing

I have download a GeoTIFF file from NASA worldview website (https://go.nasa.gov/2E8yomU), under "take a snapshot", format -> geoTIFF.

When I open it in QGIS, I can't put it in edit mode. When I go to the properties, it does not let me to select or unselect "read only". How to put this file into edit mode?

[image]

Comment: What do you want to edit on a raster?

Comment: I want to add a scale bar and mark a location

Comment: You can do this in the print composer.